# Google route planner zoom center

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im using Google route planner on my website with directions panel on the side. When you click on certain part of a jurney it gets zoomed in on the map but its not centered. Is it possible to center it in the midle of the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implemented option to control anything when you click on the panel.

But what you can do: When you click on the panel, the infoWindow opens. 
You may create your own infoWindow-object  and pass it as infoWindow-option to the directionsRenderer.

Then you'll be able to control the infoWindow. Observe the domready-event of the infoWindow(it will fire before the infoWindow opens), and set the center of the map to the value returned by the getPosition()-method of the infoWindow.

```
// Show directions
if(!Demo.iw){
  Demo.iw=new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  google.maps.event
    .addListener(Demo.iw,'domready',
                 function(){Demo.map.setCenter(this.getPosition());});
}
Demo.dirRenderer.setOptions({
                    map         : Demo.map,
                    panel       : Demo.dirContainer,
                    infoWindow  : Demo.iw,
                    directions  : dirResult
});
```

Comment: hey again, i have almost the same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952810/show-info-window-in-center-of-the-map-google-avoid-highways), could you plz help me again? i got an answer there but its not nearly as good as this one here

Comment: It looks like the problem is not almost the same, it's exactly the same, so my answer also would be the same.